# Zooming on gameObject not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I have asked before how to get a "squeeze" zooming function with the HTC-Vive controllers. Now, I have implemented the functionality and it works pretty decently.

Only, I am facing one big issue. If I am pulling both triggers on the HTC Vive, the zooming in/out is working fine. But after I changed the scale of the GameObject (that is how I zoom) and I press both triggers again, the gameObject size resets to the values that I have set.

Okay so what I am actually doing in the code is I calculate the difference between the start position and the current position of the Vive controllers. 
This gives me a usually a value between 1.0 and -1.0. With that value I should be able to zoom in or out right?

It is not working well. The gameObject changes but when I press both the triggers again, the size goes away.

I think u guys get the point, if something is unclear, please tell me.

I would appreciate any help or insight

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't update `CurrentGlobeSize`, whenever you zoom again

After

```
// Setting start position
StartPosition = Vector3.Distance(LeftHand.transform.position, RightHand.transform.position) / 100;
HasStartPosition = true;
```

Add

```
 CurrentGlobeSize = GlobeScaling.transform.localScale;
```

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow. I do not have access to the Vive at this moment. Thanks for ur reaction.

Comment: I am happy to say that ur code did the thing. Thanks.